# Can I code in both LUA and Java in Cocos2d-x?

Tags: cocos2d-x

Right now I'm using Corona SDK so I have experience with LUA but I need to implement some features in Java but I would still like to use LUA as the "main" language. Is this possible in Cocos2d-x?

Another question is if native objects will always be on top as in Corona SDK? Maybe this is not a Corona specific problem, but maybe a thing with the devices?

Comment: Cocos2d-x provides binding for Lua and Javascript but the main language is C++. There's no support for Java (except some jni code for Android). What do you mean by "native objects will always be on top"?

Comment: @LaurentZubiaur In Corona if I have a native.webView or native.mapView they will always be on top which means I can never add a picture on top of a Google Map for example.

Answer (score 0):

there is a javascript binding and Lua binding but no java check alternative game engine for java like [Slick2D](http://slick.ninjacave.com/)